# Entity Framework added extra `s` to table name in runtime query if add `PluralizingTableNameConvention` to avoid extra `s` it throw error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have simple context with 3 tables.

database tables are already present but using code first approach.

Model Device.cs is -

```
 public class Device
    {
        public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }

    }

public class sampledbContext : DbContext
    {
        public sampledbContext ()
           : base("name=sampledbContext ")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

          modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }
    }
```

To avoid extra `s` I have added above line into `OnModelCreating` but it is giving an error -

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The model backing the 'sampledbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).'
```

Database was already created and I try to use code first approach here.
I have not done update-database yet.

I tried doing `Enable-Migration` and `Update-database` it creates table with name `s` like `Devices` why ? `s` is added ?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The model backing the 'sample dbContext' context has changed since the database was created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've turned off auto-migrations in the line:

```
Database.SetInitializer<IoTSimulatordbContext>(null);
```

And therefore you will need to run update-database manually to update the model (you can run this via package manager console). If you have any data in your tables it is likely that the migration will fail due to the possibility of losing data, in that case you will need to either delete all data from the tables first or make a custom migration script to handle copying the data first.  As this seems like a test it may be better to restart the migration project with the pluralisation off from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a DataAnnotation to describe the Schema and Table name to your Table class such as this;

> [Table("Device", Schema = "MySchema")]

This will give you more control over the naming.